Ejecutar script python desde php
Buen dia tengo mi siguiente archivo python, quiero poder ejecutarlo desde un archivo php quisiera saber si esta correcto la manera en como lo estoy queriendo ejecutar desde mi archivo php.
El problema es que al ejecutar el archivo php no se esta ejecutando mi archivo python ya que la carpeta donde deberian estar copiados los archivos no tiene nada, pero si ejecuto directamente el archivo python reviso la carpeta y ahora si ya tiene los archivos.
Entonces quiero saber si hay algo malo en mi forma de ejecutar mi archivo python desde php.
Tengo ambos archivos en el mismo proyecto en mi carpeta htdocs
transfer_FTP.py
from ftplib import FTP

servidor = "server"
user = "USER"
passw = ""

try:
    conexion = FTP(servidor)
    conexion.login(user, passw)
    print ("[+] conexion establecida correctamente")
except Exception as e:
    print ("[-] No se pudo establecer la conexion al servidor" + str(e))


# Cambia al directorio donde se encuentran los archivos .csv
conexion.cwd('/ruta/carpeta/')

# Lista todos los archivos en el directorio actual
archivos = conexion.nlst()

# Filtra solo los archivos .csv
archivos_csv = [archivo for archivo in archivos if archivo.endswith('.csv')]

# Para cada archivo .csv, descárgalo y guárdalo en el directorio local
for archivo in archivos_csv:
    with open('//ruta/a/la/carpeta/' + archivo, 'wb') as f:
        conexion.retrbinary('RETR ' + archivo, f.write)


Y tengo el siguiente codigo php copy_file.php
<?php
    $command = escapeshellcmd('pruebas/test.py');
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;
?>


Y cual es el problema?

Que al ejecutar mi archivo copy_file.php
Mi script python no se ejecuta reviso la carpeta donde deverian estar copiados los archivos y no estan.
Pero si ejecuto directamente el script python si se copian los archivos.
Quiero saber si esta correcto mi php

Y alguien llama  a ese php???

Se ejecuta directamente desde el navegador ya que la idea es que el archivo se refresque cada hora y el refresh se definira mediante codigo php

navegador = cliente.. el python esta en el cliente?

Si el python esta en la misma carpeta que el php dentro del htdocs y las carpetas que se utilizan en el archivo python una es ftp y la otra es una compartida.
La carpeta en el htdocs de mi xammp se llama python_test.

puede que sea permisos, import os // print(os.getuid()) te dirá que usuario ejecuta el python llamado desde php debería ser el servidor web ( www-data si es apache )

a ver.. una vez que estas en el navegador, estas en el cliente.. no importa donde este eso.. se entiende??? alguien llama a ese php, no? o ese php esta dentro del html? y en ese caso, quien lo ejecutaria? tenes claro que si esto no fuera en tu pc, no andaria, no?

Si estoy consiente de ello, por eso se esta almacenando en un server desde el cual se ejecuta el archivo php al llamarlo desde el navegador
172.30.xx.xx/python_test/copy_file.php
Y el copy_fyle.php


sistema operativo? php está como mod o fpm?

Sistema operativo windows 11

Has probado: pclose(popen($command, 'r')); Donde $command = 'start /b python.exe el_script.py arg_1 arg_2... arg_n' Los args son opcionales. Lo que hace es crear un 'subproceso' que no espera que termine (no bloquea el navegador). Mira este ejemplo.

@gbianchi, cuando navengas a una url por ejemeplo http://172.30.xx.xx/python_test/copy_file.php este archivo php se va a ejecutar en el backend antes de ofrecer una salida, entonces puede incovar un proceso o comando del sistema y ejecutarlo siempre y cuando el servicio web tenga los permisos de ejecucion... una vez finaliza, podras ver el output del php o algun error , la resolucion de lo que ha pasado ...

@AlbertoCruz no entiendo por que requieres ejecutar un archivo .py para hacer la transferencia de archivo por FTP cuando ya PHP lo puede manejar ... sin requerir script externos en otros lenguajes ... puedes justificar esta necesidad absurda que tienes???

Ok vamos por partes, primero que nada te diré que considero esto del script en Python personalmente innecesario porque PHP tiene las capacidades de hacer conexiones FTP y mover archivos masivamente tal cual un CLI.
El llamar a un aplicativo de terceros puede traer inestabilidad o algún error no controlado, interrumpa la correcta ejecución del sistema.
Como invocar un archivo Python para su ejecución:

Evaluar desde que sistema estas y/o vas a ejecutar el script:

<?php
// Ruta al archivo Python
$pythonScript = 'python_test/transfer_FTP.py';

// Verificar el sistema operativo actual
$os = strtoupper(PHP_OS_FAMILY);

// Comando para ejecutar el script Python según el sistema operativo
if ($os === 'WINDOWS') {
    // Comando para Windows
    $command1 = 'powershell -Command "Get-Command python"';
    $command2 = "python $pythonScript";
} else {
    // Comando para Linux y macOS
    $command1 = "command -v python";
    $command2 = "python3 $pythonScript";
}

Nota: hasta este punto ya hemos determinado el Sistema Operativo y el comando que queremos ejecutar.

Antes de ejecutar el comando, debemos validar que este es un comando existente en el sistema:

$output = shell_exec($command1);

// Verificar si la salida contiene la información de la versión de Python
if (strpos($output, 'Python') !== false) {
    echo "Python está instalado en tu sistema.";
    //Metodo que ejecuta tu archivo py
    runPY($command2);
} else {
    echo "Python no está instalado en tu sistema.";
    //Mensaje de Error controlado para el output.
}

Output en Windows test terminal:


entonces se viene el método para ejecutar el comando...

function runPY(string $command)
{
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    var_export($output); // unsa salidita de datos para ver que fue lo que paso en la ejecucion.
}

Ref php-os-family: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-os-family
Ref polyfill antes de php7.2:
https://github.com/symfony/polyfill/blob/1.x/src/Php72/Php72.php#L70
Ref shell-exec:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec
Nota: As-is esta implementación no pude probarla porque no tengo PHP instalado.
PHP y su forma nativa de mover archivos:
Como te decía, PHP tiene su forma nativa de hacer lo que intentas con el script Python:
<?php
// Configuración de conexión FTP
$ftp_server = "ftp.example.com"; // Cambia esto al nombre de tu servidor FTP
$ftp_username = "tu_usuario"; // Cambia esto a tu nombre de usuario FTP
$ftp_password = "tu_contraseña"; // Cambia esto a tu contraseña FTP

// Directorio remoto y local
$remote_dir = "/directorio_remoto"; // Cambia esto al directorio remoto que deseas descargar
$local_dir = "/directorio_local"; // Cambia esto al directorio local donde deseas guardar los archivos descargados

// Establecer conexión FTP
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
if (!$conn_id) {
    die("No se pudo conectar al servidor FTP");
}

// Iniciar sesión FTP
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_password);
if (!$login_result) {
    die("Error al iniciar sesión en el servidor FTP");
}

// Cambiar al directorio remoto
if (!ftp_chdir($conn_id, $remote_dir)) {
    die("No se pudo cambiar al directorio remoto: $remote_dir");
}

// Obtener lista de archivos en el directorio remoto
$files = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");

// Descargar archivos uno por uno
foreach ($files as $file) {
    // Nombre de archivo local
    $local_file = $local_dir . "/" . basename($file);

    // Descargar el archivo
    if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $file, FTP_BINARY)) {
        echo "Archivo descargado correctamente: $file<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Error al descargar el archivo: $file<br>";
    }
}

// Cerrar conexión FTP
ftp_close($conn_id);

IMPORTANTE: para que tanto el invocado del archivo PY o el método nativo FTP funcione, apache, nginx, iis o cualquiera que sea el servicio web que ejecutara el archivo .php, tanto el servicio como el usuario owner del servicio deberán tener permisos y privilegios de ejecución y escritura para poder poner los archivos en el directorio local, de lo contrario es posible que salte un error de permisos o no ocurra nada ...

Muchas gracias me ayudo mucho tu respuesta
Tenias razon en cuanto el metodo ejecutarlo directamente en php, sinceramente no lo considere

php puede hacer muchas cosas ... es como un toolbox

Si la verdad me bloquie y me cerre en python
